# AppleScript to run .jar and pass name of dropped file as argument

Tags: jar, applescript

I want to run a jar file that has a filename as argument. This filename should be the one of a file that is dropped onto the .app (the AppleScript)

I'm a newbie in AppleScript, so any help would be appreciated!

thanks!

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184236/on-mac-o-s-how-to-get-the-name-of-files-that-has-been-dropped-onto-apple-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that there is an AppleScript command to run the jar file, so instead you could run a snippit of shell scripting from within the AppleScript. For example:

```
on open jarFiles
    tell application "Finder"
        repeat with currentJar in jarFiles
            set the shellScript to "java -jar " & ¬
                quoted form of ((name of currentJar) as text)
            do shell script shellScript
        end repeat
    end tell
end open
```

This example will open one or more dropped jar files. Note that the explicit line of code, tell application "Finder", means that the Finder's alias type will be used (which is necessary to get the name of the *currentJar* successfully.

The *on open* handler is the handler that is run on the event that the user drops one or more files onto the AppleScript (with the files being pased to the first argument, name *jarFiles* in this case).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! But actually it's not the jar files I drop. I have one jarfile and this jarfile is supposed to get a dropped file's name as argument. So suppose I drop "1.txt" on my script, the script is supposed to run a specific jarfile with the dropped file's name as argument. But I think this will not make much difference, I will just adjust your suggestion! Thanks again!

Comment: I try using "set the shellScript to "java -jar bundleID.jar " & (name of currentFile)" but I get an error stating "name of item 1 of{alias "Macintosh HD:pathtofile:file.name"} cannot be converted to type Unicode text"    Any help?

Comment: I think this is to do with AppleScript's primitive 'alias' type and the 'Finder' application's 'alias' type (which are slightly different). We want to use the Finder's type, so try placing this code within a "tell application "Finder"" block in order to explicitly use the Finder's 'alias' object. I've edited my example to include this change.

Comment: Sorry - you also need to cast using the "as" keyword to text. So (name of currentJar) should be ((name of currentJar) as text). Again, I've updated the code. :)

Comment: There's a bug/security flaw in the code as you have it; if you're passing text to the shell, *always* pass it as the `quoted form of ...`.  Otherwise, a file as simple as `~/Documents/Business Receipts/Billing.pdf` will fail because it'll be treated as two documents, and someone could name a file `; rm -rf ~` to do nasty things to your system.  I took the liberty of fixing this; I hope you don't mind.  **Edit:** Also, I don't think you need the `tell application "Finder"` block, but I didn't test that.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Now I get "Unable to access ..." Guess that has to do with permissions?!