# How to detect files (even in subfolders) with a specific extension and open them?

Tags: file, applescript, finder

I'm trying to make a droplet applscript app. It should do:

- when a folder is dropped it should "scan" the folder,its subfolders and files
- every file with a specific extension (such as: .txt" should be opened in an program and something should be done
- that's all

I get this error when I detected the right file and if it is trying to open it (the app won't be started- before that I get this error and the script cancels):`class nmxt of alias "the path to the file" could not be read`
Currently my script:

```
on open {input}
    set theFiles to (getFilesRecursively(input, "plhs"))
    repeat with oneFile in theFiles
        if name extension of oneFile is "plhs" then
            tell application "Applic"
                open oneFile
                activate
                tell application "System Events"
                    tell process "Applic"
                        click menu item "Save" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end if
    end repeat
end open


on getFilesRecursively(fContainer, fExt)
    tell application "Finder"
        set recursiveFileList to entire contents of fContainer as alias list

        set resultFileList to {}
        repeat with aFile in recursiveFileList
            if name extension of aFile contains fExt then
                set resultFileList to resultFileList & aFile
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
    return resultFileList
end getFilesRecursively
```

Comment: Similar Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713428/restrict-file-types-on-droplet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a germinal script that should get you going:

```
property kTargetFileExtension : "txt"
property pValidFileList : {}

on open of theFiles -- Executed when files or folders are dropped on the script

    set fileCount to (get count of items in theFiles)

    repeat with thisFile from 1 to fileCount
        set theFile to item thisFile of theFiles

        tell application "System Events"
            set file_info to get info for theFile
        end tell

        if visible of file_info is true then -- check for the file extension here as well
            if folder of file_info is true then
                my createList(theFile)
            else
                set fileName to name of file_info
                set targetFileFound to isTargetFile(fileName, kTargetFileExtension) of me

                if (targetFileFound) then
                    set end of pValidFileList to theFile
                end if
            end if
        end if

    end repeat

    display dialog "pValidFileList = " & pValidFileList
    (* do something with your files listed in pValidFileList here *)
end open

on createList(mSource_folder)
    set item_list to ""

    tell application "System Events"
        set item_list to get the name of every disk item of (mSource_folder as alias)
    end tell

    set item_count to (get count of items in item_list)

    repeat with i from 1 to item_count
        set the_properties to ""

        set the_item to item i of the item_list
        set fileName to the_item
        set the_item to ((mSource_folder & the_item) as string) as alias

        tell application "System Events"
            set file_info to get info for the_item
        end tell

        if visible of file_info is true then -- check for the file extension here as well
            if folder of file_info is true then
                my createList(the_item)
            else
                set targetFileFound to isTargetFile(fileName, kTargetFileExtension) of me

                if (targetFileFound) then
                    set end of pValidFileList to the_item
                end if
            end if
        end if

    end repeat
end createList

on isTargetFile(theFilename, theTargetExtension) -- (string, string) as boolean
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
    set fileNameList to every text item of theFilename
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""

    try
        set theFileExtension to item 2 of fileNameList as string
    on error
        return false
    end try

    if theFileExtension is theTargetExtension then
        return true
    end if

    return false
end isTargetFile
```

*A couple things to note:*

System Events is the current best practice for getting lists and information about files. Just asking for the entire contents is faster but known to be unreliable. This method of crawling manually is slower but there is no doubt you will be getting the files you need.

`isTargetFile` actually just works with the filename as a string, as opposed to relying on the system to give the information. Six of one, half dozen of the other if you ask me, but this does reduce the number of calls to the system, so I imagine it makes this a bit faster.

I also tend to add an `on run {}` block to these things to allow for manual selection of a folder. Doing so also facilitates testing.

*How to use:*

Save the script as an application, and you should get a droplet (the Applescript application icon with the arrow pointing down).

`on open of theFiles` is the equivalent of `main()`. You can drop any combination of files and folders onto the droplet, and it will handle the rest. It ends up with a list of target files that you can then loop through for processing. I will leave it as an exercise for you to add in that bit.

To customize the target, change the string in the first line, `property kTargetFileExtension : "txt"`, to whatever extension you are looking for. This can also be changed to an array—`property kTargetFileExtension : {"txt", "rtf", "doc}` for example—but you will also need to update `isTargetFile(theFilename, theTargetExtension)` to loop through those as well.

Beyond that, this just works. Right now, it will gather a list of `txt` files for processing.

Add salt to taste.

Comment: You're right. That's a crummy answer. I'm working on a new one now.

Comment: @cocos2dbeginner: I have updated my answer to something you can use almost right out of the box.

Comment: @cocos2dbeginner: It worked for me, but Applescript is sometimes weird about its precompiling. `fileName` is in one place in that script, but it looks as though it wasn't being populated properly. It should be fixed now.